vegan decorana() function - negative values error
I am trying to do a DCA in R with vegan package and decorana() function for a vegetation dataset. the Dataset consists of plots in rows, with abundance of dif. plant species in colums. When running
 dca_result <- decorana(species_data)

I get back
Error in decorana(species_data) : 
  'decorana' cannot handle negative data entries

the Data looks like this
str(species_data)

'data.frame':   419 obs. of  174 variables:
 $ Agrostis.canina              : num  0 2.5 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 6.5 ...
 $ Agrostis.stolonifera         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Ajuga.reptans                : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Anthoxantum.odoratum         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Avenella.flexuosa            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Ahtyrium.filix.femina        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Betula.pendula               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Struthiopteris.spicant       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Calamagrostis.arundinacea    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Callitriche.spec             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Calluna.vulgaris             : num  3.5 0 0 0 18 0 0 0.2 0 0 ...

I did
library(fixr)
check_for_negative_values(species_data)

it returns
Data frame does not contain negative values.
NULL

EDIT:
I also ran this code but it also returns FALS
any_negative <- any(species_data[,-1] < 0)


print(any_negative)

so there should be no negative values right, what could be the problem then?

I think you should send your complaint to the fixr package: if decorana finds negative values in your data, you have negative values in your data. decorana does not use any fancy packages, but just the simple if(any(species_data < 0) stop("'decorana' cannot handle negative data entries").  You could try the same test: you have negative values if any of the values are < 0.

Hi jari, thx for your reply, thats odd, its is abundance data of plants, there should be no 0, I will check again

I also ran:
any_negative <- any(species_data[,-1] < 0)
print(any_negative)
and got back FALSE

some factors and character variables can give the same error. All your data entries should be numeric.

Two ways to check that data are numeric: is.numeric(species_data[,-1]) or sum(species_data[,-1]).

Hi Jari, thank you. I found the problem, It was a non numeric cell that was introduced when transposing the data long/wide format.

fine! I'm going to add a test to catch those cases with less cryptic error messages.

Super, thank you very much!
